# Postgresql MAX en HORA

Tags: sql, postgresql

Tengo la siguiente query donde quiero obtener el mayor de hora ingresado. Pero por algún motivo obtengo el Máximo de hora `9:30`, el dato correcto seria `12:30`

Aqui la query `SELECT MAX(hora_termino) FROM trabajos`

```
|id|hora_inicio|hora_termino| 
---------------|------------|
| 1|  7:30     | 8:30       | 
| 2|  8:30     | 9:30       | 
| 3|  9:00     | 12:30      | 
|--------------|------------|
```

Aqui mi SQL Fiddle

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9f7870/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que tienes definido los campos de hora como `varchar`, es decir texto. Debes declarar el campo como `Time`.

```
CREATE TABLE  trabajos (
  `trabajos_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `hora_inicio` Time NOT NULL,
  `hora_termino` Time NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`trabajos_id`)
);


INSERT INTO trabajos
    (hora_inicio, hora_termino)
VALUES
    ('7:30','9:30'),
    ('8:30','8:30'),
    ('9:00','12:30');

SELECT MAX(hora_termino) FROM trabajos
```

El resultado será: 12:30:00

Comment: Hola gracias por tu respuesta, funciono perfectamente! Muchas gracias saludos